# Polynomials over finite field

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, algebra-precalculus, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I tried to calculate the characteristic polynomial of a 4x4 matrix over the finite field with two elements. I got two results: $x^4+x^3+x+1$ and $(x+1)^3$. First I thought that this must be an error, but then I noticed that actually they give the same results if we plug in either 0 or 1. So is this a possible answer, that they are the same or do I have to be wrong somewhere?

Comment: You mean $(x + 1)^4$ instead of $(x + 1)^3$, right?

Comment: no, I don't....

Comment: Then you did in fact make a mistake somewhere.

Comment: For reference, $x^4 + x^3 + x + 1$ factors as $(x+1)^2 (x^2 + x + 1)$

Answer (score 1):

It's quite possible that both of them are *annihilating polynomials* of your matrix. However, the polynomials are different: not only are the coefficients different, but the *degrees* are different too!

The minimal polynomial and the characteristic polynomial of a matrix over a field are unique (once we specify they are supposed to be monic); there is only one right answer. So at least one of your putative answers is incorrect.

---

As an aside, note we can detect the inequality by plugging in more general things than elements of $\mathbf{F}_2$: e.g. if $\alpha \in \mathbf{F}_4$ such that $\alpha \neq 0,1$, then plugging in gives

$$ (\alpha + 1)^3 = 1 $$
$$ \alpha^4 + \alpha^3 + \alpha + 1 = 0 $$

Answer (score 0):

You cannot check that two polynomials are the same by plugging values and looking at the result. Otherwise, you'll conclude that $x$ and $x^{12121}$ are the same polynomial!

Comment: Over finite fields, there is no more a bijection between polynomials and polynomial functions For instance Little Fermat says over $\mathbf F_p$ the polynomial function associated to the non-null polynomial $x^p-x$ is the null function.